# Copying specific number of chars on each line of new file (Pascal)

Tags: file, text-files, pascal

I want to create this "simple" program that reads characters (or lines) from file A and copies them into file B. While in B there would be exactly 20 characters on each line. Here is what i have so far:

```
var t,tt : text;
    i    : integer;
    s    : string;


begin
 assign(t,'a.txt');
 assign(tt,'b.txt');
 reset(t);
 rewrite(tt);
 i:=0;

 while not eof(t) do
   begin
    i:=i+1;
    if eoln(t) then readln(t);
    read(t,s[i]);
    if i=20 then
     if eof(t) then break
     else
       begin
        writeln(tt,s);
        i:=0
       end;
   end;

 write(tt,s);
 close(t);
 close(tt);
end.
```

I have tried some variations like reading into char and then copying into string, but none worked properly. Often it only created blank lines in B. I'm sure there must be other ways to do this but I would be most curious about what is wrong in this code.

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code in a debugger to see what is causing whatever problem you're having?

Comment: `readln(t)` requires a buffer argument. Valid forms are `readln(buffer)` (reading from standard input) or `readln(f, buffer)` (reading from text file, `f`). So `readln(t)` doesn't look right. You're also not handling the string correctly. See, for example, this lesson on [Pascal strings](http://pascal-programming.info/lesson12.php).

Comment: Stepping didn't work - it freezed and I had to restart it. Maybe I should try creating some writes inside the code to see what's going on with the variables.  

Ok, I wasn´t sure about it and I've seen the string page, although didn't read it quite through. Thanks for the info, I will maybe try replacing the string with normal array and do some other changes. Then try to see what the program is doing and report back here with updates.

Comment: lurker: the readln is fine. He reads char for char with read(), and when eoln becomes true he only consumes the line ending. That being said, he should think about what happens with excess characters on the line.

Comment: I think that the problem is that you need a 'read (t, s[i])' before the 'while not eof (t)'. I would use a repeat/until loop.

Comment: No'am Newman: Ok great, that somehow worked! Although it worked even when I removed it so I don't really know what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it somehow finally started working, but the server that I send the solution to marked it as wrong.. Anyway, here is the final code that works on my PC if anyone's interested. Thanks for the tips guys.

```
var t,tt : text;
    i,k  : integer;
    s,x  : string;


begin
 assign(t,'a.txt');
 assign(tt,'b.txt');
 reset(t);
 rewrite(tt);
 i:=0;

 while not eof(t) do
   begin
    i:=i+1;
    if eoln(t) then readln(t,x);
    read(t,s[i]);
    if i=20 then
     if eof(t) then break
     else
       begin
        for k:=1 to 19 do
        write(tt,s[k]);
        writeln(tt,s[20]);
        i:=0
       end;
   end;

 for k:=1 to i do
 write(tt,s[k]);
 close(t);
 close(tt);
end.
```